# Difference in minutes between two datetime fields

Tags: formula, formula-field, datetime

I need to calculate the difference in minutes between two datetime fields inside a formula.

The following works if the dates are different

```
(date2__c-date1__c)*24*60
```

But if its the same date then this fails as the difference between the two values subtracted from each other is zero.

Is there an easy solution to this?

Comment: make sure both are datetime fields i tried same code in my DE org and it worked fine for two datetime fields. even if date is same it returns expected results.

Comment: So the date dates were the same, just different hours/minutes?   If you make a formula that states just date2__c-date1__c  that should return 0.  Which is my problem.

Comment: yes day is same I just kept difference of two minutes in two dates and it returned exact time difference

Comment: Yes both are definitely datetime fields.    Can you confirm what result it returned?    The field my formula is on is a number field with no decimal points.  If I return decimal points then I do see 0.1 or something similar but this results in values that naturally include decimal places which is confusing for a minutes figure.

Comment: Yes here the trick my field having two digit after decimal points

Comment: In this case, you can change the return type of your formula to `Text` and formula will be `TEXT((date2__c-date1__c)*24*60)`

Comment: Thanks @PragatiJain feel free to answer question for some points, this is very useful!

Comment: @AdamJones please find my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Difference b/w two date time would never be 0 until you have exact date time value. So in your case, you can resolve your issue either by changing the return type of formula field to `TEXT` or `NUMBER(With 0 Decimal Places)`.

1. If you changed the return type to `TEXT` then the formula would be :

   ```
   TEXT((date2__c - date1__c)*24*60)
   ```
2. If you changed the return type to `NUMBER(With 0 Decimal Places)` then the formula would be :

   ```
   (date2__c - date1__c)*24*60
   ```

I would prefer to go with the 2nd option.

Comment: How we can calculate the mins between only 8 hour shift?